# How can I run an external program without waiting for it to exit?

Tags: c++, c, linux

I'm trying to execute an external program from inside my Linux C++ program.

I'm calling the method `system("gedit")` to launch an instance of the Gedit editor. However my problem is while the Gedit window is open, my C++ program waits for it to exit.

How can I call an external program without waiting for it to exit?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will need to use `fork` and `exec`

```
int fork_rv = fork();
if (fork_rv == 0)
{
    // we're in the child
    execl("/path/to/gedit", "gedit", 0);

    // in case execl fails
    _exit(1);
}
else if (fork_rv == -1)
{
    // error could not fork
}
```

You will also need to reap your child so as not to leave a zombie process.

```
void reap_child(int sig)
{
    int status;
    waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG);
}

int main()
{
    signal(SIGCHLD, reap_child);
    ...
}
```

In regards to zombie processes, you have a second option.  It uses a bit more resources (this flavor forks twice), but the benefit is you can keep your wait closer to your fork which is nicer in terms of maintenance.

```
int fork_rv = fork();
if (fork_rv == 0)
{
    fork_rv = fork();
    if (fork_rv == 0)
    {
        // we're in the child
        execl("/path/to/gedit", "gedit", 0);

         // if execl fails
        _exit(1);
    }
    else if (fork_rv == -1)
    {
        // fork fails
        _exit(2);
    }

    _exit(0);
}
else if (fork_rv != -1)
{
    // parent wait for the child (which will exit quickly)
    int status;
    waitpid(fork_rv, &status, 0);
}
else if (fork_rv == -1)
{
    // error could not fork
}
```

What this last flavor does is create a child, which in turns creates a grandchild and the grandchild is what exec's your gedit program.  The child itself exits and the parent process can reap it right away.  So an extra fork but you keep all the code in one place.

Comment: can you give an example how to use fork and exec together to call gedit?

Comment: You should use `_exit` instead of `exit` here: otherwise you might end up with artifacts such as the same buffers being flushed by two different processes.

Comment: Yay.  Now, more nitpicks: you could use `signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN)`, but if you install a signal handler, you should really use `sigaction` because `signal` has varying historical behaviors on different UNIXes whereas `sigaction` is more standardized (and more general).  And what happens if multiple children should be reaped but you only enter the `SIGCHLD` handler once?

Comment: How do i pass an argument to gedit ?

Also i'm getting a warning while calling execl()

warning: missing sentinel in function call

Comment: To pass arguments to gedit, add extra parameters to your exec call `execl("/path/to/gedit", "gedit", "arg1", "arg2", 0);`  Make sure you have that last `0`, that's the missing sentinel.

Answer (score 3):

Oh, let me say it!

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork-exec

Fork!  :)

Comment: thanks for the link, i have a better understanding of fork reading that.

Answer (score 1):

First, did you try to launch in background with `system("gedit&")`?

If that does not work, try spawning a new thread and running gedit from there.

I presume that you are not concerned with the result of the edit, or the contents of the edited file?

Comment: Just tried that, works well. Thanks for providing a different approach.